# Can't create CustomSurfaceView

Tags: android, xml, surfaceview

I have a CustomSurfaceView. And I cant create this in my application. What's problem? I created all constructions, and have no idea why i have  Error inflating class. Here's my code:

```
public class CustomSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
Camera mCamera;

CustomSurfaceView(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    init();
}
CustomSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
{
    super(context, attributeSet);

    init();
}
CustomSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);

    init();
}

public void init()
{
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    mCamera = Camera.open();
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h )
{
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
    {
        return;
    }


    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }


    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
    {
        return;
    }


    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }

    mCamera = null;
}
}
```

And i've tried create this View in XML file. This is XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".mainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.example.orientationsensor.CustomSurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name = "com.example.orientationsensor.CustomSurfaceView"/>
```

And I have an error with creating with. Android Studio throw me this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.orientationsensor/com.example.orientationsensor.mainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class CustomSurfaceView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have a solve for this problem. I should create attrs.xml in values and write this :

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomSurfaceView">

</declare-styleable>
```

Also need change contsructor's privacy to public